# A question about a regex expression from Jaden Casing Strings with JS (a kata from Codewars)

Tags: javascript, regex

Been stupid around lately. Recently I had no idea about how to capture every first letter in the string. I googled. As I understood, `\b` matches every first letter plus space before them. So, I wrote a regex: `(\b)[^']` and it works perfectly with strings except for the part with the short form like *'aren't' or 'doesn't'*. My reg captures this *'t'* that shouldn't be captured. Could you tell me what is wrong with my reg?

Thanks ahead. I am a beginner, so I am sorry if I have a dumb code xd

**Code:**

```
String.prototype.toJadenCase = function () {
    return this.replace(/(\b)[^']/g, function(x) { 
        return x.toUpperCase();
    });
}
// output: How Can Mirrors Be Real If Our Eyes Aren'T Real
console.log("How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real".toJadenCase());
// output: Most Trees Are Blue
console.log('most Trees Are Blue'.toJadenCase());
// output: Why This Doesn'T Work
console.log("why This Doesn't work".toJadenCase());
```

Comment: Your premise is false. `\b` doesn't match a character. It has zero width. It anchors your regex to transitions between word (`\w`) and non-word (`\W`) character classes.

Comment: You will find a clear definition of a *word boundary* (`\b`) (sometimes called a *word break*) [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I understood, `\b` matches every first letter plus space before them.

This is not really what it does. It doesn't match a character. It matches a *position* without matching a single character. The position is matched when exactly *one* character among the character before and character after that position is alphanumeric (or underscore).

So in this particular task you have to avoid a match with `'t`, since the `\b` will match the position between these two characters. So you could use a look-behind check, to check that the character *before* that position is not a `'`. You should also check that the character *after* that position is the one that is the letter, as otherwise you'll also match the position just after every word.

So use: `/(?<!')\b[a-z]/g`

The `(?<!')` part asserts that the preceding character is not a quote